# using arraylist spinner multiline not working

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

R.layout.spinner_rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/cust_view"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:singleLine="false"

    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

spinner ID

```
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/vaultAudit"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    />
```

below are the array adapter value:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAnsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HeaderInfo.this,R.layout.spinner_rows, ArrayListObject);
                        spinnerAnsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_rows);
                        ans.setAdapter(spinnerAnsAdapter);
```

Display like this :[image]

hidding text how to rectify pls give some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already face it and solution is switching to dialog style spinner:

```
<Spinner
  ...
android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Comment: dear @HeminaShah, spinner cut the contents if more than one line, therefore you have to use a dialog style spinner, So pleases try it on own.